# Sum of Special Series involving exponents

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation, geometric-series

What is the sum to $n$ terms of the series $$2(2^0)+ 3(2^1) + 4(2^2) + \cdots$$

My try:- The $n$th term is $$(n+1)(2^{n-1}) = n(2^{n-1}) + 2^{n-1}.$$ So the sum is the summation of these two terms. I know the summation of the second term using G.P. sum but I do not know the summation of the first term as it involves multiplication.

I would also like to know other ways of finding the sum.

Sorry for the poor presentation, I do not know how to use Latex.

Thank you.

Comment: See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) regarding formatting

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy What leads you to believe that the OP wishes to sum an infinite series?

Comment: Sorry for the syntax, I’m on mobile. Given $f(x)=x^n$ you have that $f’(x)=nx^{n-1}$. So compute the sum of $x^n$ (which is geometric), then you apply the derivative, and at the end value at $x=2$. This works since for finite terms the derivarive is linear so you can first sum, an later derive and you’d get the same result as just summing the derivatives of the function.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Those merely indicate that one should infer a pattern for the remaining elements of the series. The question concerns "the sum to $n$ terms of the series."

Comment: @RamKeswani Multiply the sum by $(1-2)^2=1-2\cdot2+2^2$. Don't add, but instead distribute the multiplication. Most of the terms will cancel and you will be left with a fixed number of terms. Then the sum will be equal to those few terms divided by $(1-2)^2$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**

Consider
$$\sum_{n=0}^p (n+1)x^n=\sum_{n=0}^p nx^n+\sum_{n=0}^p x^n=x\sum_{n=0}^p nx^{n-1}+\sum_{n=0}^p x^n$$

When done, make $x=2$

Answer (score 0):

It is an AGP. So,
$S_n=2.2^0+3.2^1+4.2^2+ ........          +(n+1).2^{n-1}$

Multiply the equation by 2

$S_{n}=2.2^0+3.2^1+4.2^2+ ........          +(n+1).2^{n-1}+0$
$2.S_n=0+2.2^1+3.2^2+4.2^3+ .....  +n.2^{n-1}     +(n+1).2^{n}$
Now subtracting 
$S_n=-2-(2^1+2^2+....+2^{n-1})+(n+1).2^n$

$S_n $ can be easily found from here